# How do you swap two variables of any type without using third in swift?

Tags: swift

I know how to swap **int** like below:

```
var x = 5
var y = 7

x = x + y
y = x - y
x = x - y

print(x)
print(y)
```

But how can I swap two variables of any other type without using a third variable ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use tuples!

```
var a = "a"
var b = "b"
(b, a) = (a, b)
```

This works for any type, or any number of variables.

Another way that is similar to your approach with `Int`s:

```
a += b
b = String(a.dropLast(b.count))
a = String(a.dropFirst(b.count))
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Is there any other way @Sweeper ? Like advance operator ?

Comment: Or simply `swap(&a, &b)`

Comment: @ArafinRussell I have added another way that's quite similar to what you did with `Int`s. Or like Martin R suggested, use `swap`.

Comment: Btw, both the tuple assignment and the swap function use *some* intermediate storage, they do not *“swap two variables of any type without using third in swift”*

Comment: @MartinR, Well, technically, result of arithmetic operation is stored in some intermediate storage before assignment too.