# How do you exchange values in tuples with each other using an intermediate tuple?

Tags: swift

```swift
var human1 = (name: "Mike", age: 17, city: "NYC")
let oneHumanName = human1.name; let oneHumanAge = human1.age; let oneHumanCity = human1.city

var human2 = (name: "Amy", age: 15, city: "LA")
let twoHumanName = human2.name; let twoHumanAge = human2.age; let twoHumanCity = human2.city
```

How do you exchange values in tuples with each other using an additional intermediate tuple?

Comment: What is your end goal, please add the expected result

Comment: [Does this answer of mine your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55493283/5133585)

Comment: Given the comment below and the fact that a tuple is a value type I believe the answer is the basic temp = a, a = b, b =temp solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** OK I misread the question. I'll leave my original answer below because it's better. This is how you do it with an intermediate tuple.

```
var human1 = (name: "Mike", age: 17, city: "NYC")
var human2 = (name: "Amy", age: 15, city: "LA")

let intermediate = human1
human1 = human2
human2 = intermediate
```

---

Without an intermediate

You can have tuples of tuples so the following will work:

```
(human2, human1) = (human1, human2)
```

Here is an example

```
var human1 = (name: "Mike", age: 17, city: "NYC")
var human2 = (name: "Amy", age: 15, city: "LA")

print("human 1 = \(human1)")
print("human 2 = \(human2)")

print("swapping")
(human2, human1) = (human1, human2)

print("human 1 = \(human1)")
print("human 2 = \(human2)")
```

Output:

```
human 1 = (name: "Mike", age: 17, city: "NYC")
human 2 = (name: "Amy", age: 15, city: "LA")
swapping
human 1 = (name: "Amy", age: 15, city: "LA")
human 2 = (name: "Mike", age: 17, city: "NYC")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But according to the task, you need to exchange values in tuples using an additional intermediate tuple

Comment: @Alluroso Sorry, misread your question. I thought it said *without* an intermediate. I'll add an example

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. There is a method called swap exactly for this purpose. `swap(&human1, &human2)`

Comment: @LeoDabus You could argue that the `swap` method is reinventing the wheel because there's a perfectly good and quite elegant language construct that will do it for you :) . Anyway, the question asks  for a method using a temporary intermediate variable.