# How can I swap two variables without using a temporary variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know how to swap integers with a temporary variable, like this:

```
let x = 5;
let y = 7;

x = x + y;
y = x - y
x = x - y;
```

But how can I swap two variables of any type without using a third variable ?

Comment: By the way, instead of the more expensive mathematical operations to swap numbers, you can simply use XOR: `x ^= y, y ^= x, x ^= y;` :)

Comment: @code The OP's trick works on floats, as long as they don't run out of precision; the XOR trick only works on 32-bit ints. They are not equivalent (though obviously either is fine for `5` and `7`).

Comment: @Amadan the OP used the word "integers", not numbers.

Comment: @code In JavaScript, all numbers (except `BigInt`) are floats. They get forced into int32 for bit operations, then converted back to floats. I.e. in JavaScript, OP's code succeeds with `x = 1000000000000000; y = 2000000000000000` (both integers, though internally represented as floats); your method ends up with `1233977344` and `-1530494976`.

Comment: @code Not saying your code is wrong — just that both of them have separate weaknesses. And _neither_ should ever be used, except _possibly_ in assembly, if doing something super time critical, and only after profiling. Even if deconstructing assignment did not exist, the temporary variable method is more legible, and except for requiring extra storage, doesn't have any of the weaknesses of these two methods.

Comment: @Amadan I agree, but I simply think that XOR is much more elegant for integer swapping in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered this in Javascript, although it must have been there for decades — and I see the question is asked [in lots of languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493230/how-do-you-swap-two-variables-of-any-type-without-using-third-in-swift) and the answer in Javascript is unnervingly simple.

```
[x, y] = [y, x];
```

Comment: not decades, though, I think since 2015 or so (ES6?)

Comment: That sort of thing works in Go: `x, y = y, x`, and the behavior is built into the language spec. Is the behavior you expect guaranteed by the [language specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), or is undefined and left up to the implementation?